# App Engine takes _minutes_ to load page or complete task

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine

When using the default scaling configuration I'm seeing this issue when the task queue is filling up. Instead of creating more instances the requests just wait to be executed. I get ~90 seconds latency when loading a page. Also seeing that only one instance out of few gets any requests.

I tried this configuration:

```
automatic_scaling:
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.5
  max_instances: 20
  min_pending_latency: 30ms
  max_pending_latency: 5s
  max_concurrent_requests: 50
```

but it seemed to have little effect.

What the dashboard shows:
[image]

Please advise

Comment: Did it happen over and over again?

Comment: @JMGelilio yes. This is a consistent behavior no matter what I do with the `app.yaml` config. When time intense jobs are running (tasks that iterate over a lot of values, or send log requests) app becomes unusable, and other tasks also wait for very long to be served

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your application code and whole configuration in App Engine Standard, it's hard for us to tell the cause of the latency. As an advice, you can use App Engine Flexible environment to test and compare the granular approach of the [handling of the requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-requests-are-handled). It will give you to choose the properly routing and all the flexibility you need.

If the App Engine Flexible test strategy is not feasible, you can consider the [Cloud Profiler](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/profiling-python).
This will give you all the tools to troubleshoot application latency and find the best practices based on your needs.

When all your options are exhausted and you have done everything. The last option that I can suggest is to create a [PIT](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).